# docker-compose.yaml multiple .env files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following project structure:

```
my-project/
   versions.env
   pom.xml
   build.sh
   somescript.sh
   docker/
      .env
      docker-compose.yaml
   helm
      values.yaml
```

docker-compose.yaml contains multiple services with images refs like `image: "postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"`

Currently, I have `POSTGRES_VERSION=xxxx` (and other versions) defined duplicitly in both `versions.env` (used in `build.sh->mvn build->pom.xml (${env.POSTGRES_VERSION})` and some `script.sh->skopeo copy ...`) and `docker/.env` (this .env also contains other variables, not only versions).

I would like to achieve something like

```
cd docker && docker-compose --env-file ../versions.env --env-file .env  up -d
```

But for the simplicity for other users, I would love to run it only with simplest command

```
cd docker && docker-compose up -d
```

I have been checking env_file option

```
services:
  some-service:
    env_file:
```

But it seems not to apply envs on image, only pass them to the container being started - same as

```
services:
  some-service:
    environment:
```

.env file syntax doesn't specify any "include" directive...

Is it somehow possible to work with multiple env files and define them inside .env or docker-compose.yaml?

My goal is to have images versions only in one place without having to build the project (without generating docker-compose.yaml, values.yaml locally after the build).... Right now, I have 3 locations for version - versions.env, docker/.env && helm/values.yaml

P.S. handling the helm/values.yaml is not part of this question, i will find some workaround based on this https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10026

Comment: `env_file` in `docker-compose.yaml` should do the trick: [env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#env_file). IF what you want is to modify the image, you will have to build a new one.

Comment: How does your build process use a dynamically-set PostgreSQL version?  What goes wrong if the two version numbers don't match?